# Invoke Expression while using iex in Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir, elixir-iex

I am just beginning with elixir. I created a project using "mix" and wrote the below code.

```
defmodule HelloWorld do
  def hello_world do
    IO.puts("Hello World!")
  end
end

#calling the function hello_world
HelloWorld.hello_world()
```

After that I tried to check the result using "iex -S mix" but it is giving this error:

```
Invoke-Expression : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'S'.
At line:1 char:5
+ iex -S mix
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```